# How to use GROUP BY (date) in MySQL to start at a given day of the week

Tags: mysql, group-by

If I have a MySQL query to aggregate totals by week, e.g.:

```
select sum(keyword1), sum(keyword2), sum(keyword3), dateTime
from myTable
group by week(dateTime)
order by dateTime asc
```

I find that the weeks appear to begin on a Sunday.

Can this be changed to a Monday?

Column dateTime is in MySQL Timestamp format 2011-09-26 12:34:32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysql> select week('2011-09-25', 1);
+-----------------------+
| week('2011-09-25', 1) |
+-----------------------+
|                    38 |
+-----------------------+

mysql> select week('2011-09-25', 0);
+-----------------------+
| week('2011-09-25', 0) |
+-----------------------+
|                    39 |
+-----------------------+
```

So, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format

Comment: So it's a system value? That makes sense.

Comment: FAO Ajreal: Thanks. I found it under Advanced in Options in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 7):

You want the sunday to belong to the previous week so remove one day from it

```
select sum(keyword1), sum(keyword2), sum(keyword3),  week(DATE_SUB(dateTime, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) my_week
from myTable
group by week(DATE_SUB(dateTime, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
order by my_week asc
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS) my_week 
from myTable

Comment: there a missing parenthese, sorry ;-)